# IndexError al guardar variables en una lista

Tags: python

Obtengo una serie de valores (son contornos de una imagen) y los guardo en una lista llamada *contours*.

Lo que pretendo después que es en caso de que haya contornos, es decir que la lista sea superior a 0, recorrer esta lista, e ir guardando una serie de datos. etc. **Hasta aquí todo bien.** La parte de tratamiento de imagen con OpenCV no hay problema.

El problema es que yo quiero guardar los valores del punto central de la figura estudiada. Y para ello he creado una lista para la coordenada X y otra para la Y. Y un contador para ir variando el índice de la lista.

```
cnt= 0    
centroX = []
centroY = []
```

La cosa es que cuando yo voy a trabajar con ellas, me sale el error:

> centroX[cnt] = x + np.int(w/2)
>
> IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Y no entiendo el motivo, ya que yo voy creando un contador llamado *cnt* e incrementándolo.

Todo el código escrito a continuación está dentro del main.

```
def main():

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

    while True:
        cnt = 0
        centroX = []
        centroY = []

        _,frame = cap.read()
        flip_frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)

        # ****************************************************************************************
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(flip_frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        _,threshold_frame = cv2.threshold(gray,254,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

        _, contours,_ = cv2.findContours(threshold_frame, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        #cv2.drawContours(flip_frame, contours, -1,(0,0,255),1)

        for contour in contours:
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)

            centroX[cnt] = x + np.int(w/2)
            centroY[cnt] = y + np.int(h/2)

            cv2.rectangle(flip_frame, (centroX[cnt], centroY[cnt]), (centroX[cnt], centroY[cnt]), (0, 0, 255), 3)
            cnt = cnt +1
        # ****************************************************************************************

        cv2.imshow('Ventana', flip_frame)

        # key events
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == 27:  # esc
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Al acceder a `lista[n]` el índice `n` debe existir. No se crea en ese momento como aparentemente piensas. Para añadir un elemento nuevo a una lista usa `lista.append(dato)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando declaras `centroX = []`, tienes una nueva lista, pero está vacía. Luego, intentas acceder al elemento `[0]` en la primera iteración, pero este elemento no existe y por ello te salta el error.

En lugar de asignar la posición con `centroX[cnt]`, podrías ir *agregando* nuevos elementos a la lista:

```
centroX.append(x + np.int(w/2))
```

Otra opción que tienes es la de inicializar la lista antes del ciclo, para que las posiciones ya existan, por ejemplo con:

```
centroX = [None]*max(contours)
```

Answer (score 0):

`centroX = [ ]` es una lista de python, que no puede ser sumada a un dato np de Numpy. Por lo que podrías transformar tu lista `centroX = []` a una usando numpy, por ejemplo:

```
`centroX = []`
```

`centroX=np.array(centroX)` y así poder sumar el dato con numpy.

Por el contrarío si deseas conservar la lista creada en python, entonces no deberías sumar un dato con numpy.

¡Espero haberte ayudado! :)